# WaitCursor doesn't appear in a C# NET CF application

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I'm running a somewhat lengthy process in a C# .NET CF application, then I want to show the hourglass mouse pointer. The code I'm using is:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
Cursor.Show();
this.Refresh();

for (int nRow = 0; ... // lengthy process
{
    Program.tblLect.Rows[nRow]["rowId"] = nRow + 1;
    // tried with this, doesn't work either
    //if ((nRow % 20)==0) 
    //    Application.DoEvents();
}

Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
```

but no cursor is shown in the form.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems ok to me.  Wonder if its dependent on the device.  Ours shows a circle with changing colors (not an hour glass).

Comment: The look of the WaitCursor depends on the OS; for OSes of the Windows XP generation and older, it's an hourglass. for Vista generation and newer, it's usually that blue/green circle.

Comment: Is this run on the UI Thread or a background thread?

Comment: @KeithS - this is *Compact* framework, so it's running on an embedded device, not XP or Vista

Comment: @ctacke: this is running in the UI thread. I tried with another thread as suggested by @Polity but this thread is updating a DataTable and ran into concurrency issues

Comment: What's your target hardware/OS?  If it's generic CE and it doesn't have Cursor support in the OS, you'd get "no cursor" behavior here.

Comment: @ctacke: WinCE 5.0 / .NET CF 2.0, running on a PsionTeklogix Neo. So far, I never saw any cursor in the device (hourglass or normal cursor). As an alternative I was looking for an animated .gif, but looks like it's not supported, maybe I can do the work with a background thread cycling a bunch of pictures :(((. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Even when calling Application.DoEvents, your application will be working ALOT and therefore is not guaranteed to update the UI. Try and keep the load off your GUI thread. For the test, just run your code on a background thread.

Comment: I tried with another thread but this I'm updating a DataTable in the background thread and ran into concurrency issues

Comment: i would recommend fixing the concurrency problems rather trying to find your way into hacking around this problem because i dont think there will be many solutions other then to constantly call Application.DoEvents or even more dirty, use a timer to slice your lengthy problem into  multiple smaller parts (ughh)

Comment: the process isn't really a lengthy problem, just a massive DataTable update. I have no problem about using Application.DoEvents and/or Thread.Sleep, but neither works for me (no cursor shown). Maybe there is a global setting that hides the cursor?

Comment: Sleep will not work anyways since that also blocks the Thread. Again, Application.DoEvents might work but showing and animating a cursor isnt a atomic operation and very dependent on the underlying implementation. Long story short. There is simply no reason to expect a 'real-time' user experience when using the GUI thread for heavy operations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Cursor.Current use

this.Current=Cursors.Waitcusrsor;

this.Cursor=Cursors.Default;